# android run a repeated task when another repeated task is finished

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

I'm having a task that executes for 10 seconds with a period of 1 second without delay and another task that executes for 30 seconds with a period of 5 seconds when the first task is finished.

Also, I need to cancel both tasks when a button is pressed.

I do not know which is the best solution for this problem.

1. I tried basic threads but will block the GUI until both tasks
   executes
2. I tried `ExecutorService executorService =
   Executors.newSingleTheadExecutor()` but i this case the
   `executor.submit(runnable)` executes one task after another but not
   each periodically
3. I tried scheduled executor with scheduled as fixed rate but the
   scheduled executor is asynchronous and I do know how to use

   ```
   executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable1, delay, period);      
   //and after finished to run
   executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable2, delay, period);
   ```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Best Regards,
AurelianR

Comment: Can you explain in other words (or a drawing) how you want them to be scheduled? I don't get it ... Task 1  "executes for 10 seconds with a period of 1 second without delay" - So every second one Task1 Instance is started? Now when exactly is the first instance of Task 2 supposed to start?

Comment: sure. Task 1 increase the sound (ring) volume with 10% at each second for 10 seconds. when this task finished the volume will be at 100%. Then  the second task decreases the volume with 15% at each 5 seconds, so at the end of the second task the volume will be at 10% of total if I am calculating right.

Comment: Did you try using a couple of `for` loops with some `Thread.sleep()` statements?

Comment: yes. this resolv my problem but blocks the ui thread until both tasks are finished.

Comment: Please elaborate your question , if possible with some example

Comment: I would say this is absolutely feasible with scheduled executor. Just schedule the tasks as one shots with according delay instead of repeating. So schedule 10 x t1 at t, t+1, t+2 ... and then 6x t2 at t+15, t+20 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CountDownTimer` class. I mocked up a simple demo.

I created a couple of `Runnable` tasks to simulate the VolumeUp and VolumeDown functions.

When `timerUp` starts it counts up for the given time. After `timerUp` counts is done, start `timerDown` in the `onFinish`. It counts down.

```
public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView out;
    int value = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

        out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);
        setText(value);

        timerUp.start();
    }

    CountDownTimer timerUp = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            runnable1.run();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerDown.start();
        }
    };

    CountDownTimer timerDown = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            runnable2.run();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.e("done", "onFinish");
        }
    };

    private void setText(final int value){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                out.setText(String.valueOf(value));
            }
        });
    }

    Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            value += 10;
            setText(value);
        }
    };

    Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            value -= 10;
            setText(value);
        }
    };
}
```

The timers can be cancelled by calling,

```
timerUp.cancel();
timerDown.cancel();
```

You may have to play around with the time values a bit. Hope you get the idea. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for doing repeated tasks.

Or you can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It allows you to do work in the background without blocking the UI thread, and then make updates to the UI when necessary.

Comment: I do know if is usable in my problem. I need to execute two task periodically, task 1 has a period of 1 second and task 2 has a period of 5 seconds. And each task updates the volume settings on UI thread.

Comment: Do you mind updating your post to include your `Thread` blocks? I assume that you're using `runOnUiThread()` to update the UI, but is it possible that you're doing too much work in `runOnUiThread()`?

Answer (score 1):

martinkbrown and K Neeraj Lal have provided some good answers for this that will help in your particular situation (you need to use an asynchronous thread to prevent blocking the UI thread), but for responding to events like these you should consider adopting the ReactiveX methodology for your project as a whole. It simplifies communicating about carefully timed events all across your application code. This is a larger scale addition that involves learning to use an open source library, but will speed up your development from here on out.

See 
http://reactivex.io/ and https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid for more info

or another good option:
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: @Fildor I agree for just this one issue, it is overkill, but not if there are a dozen issues like this throughout the code.